# Ruby on Rails Heroku 503 Error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, heroku

I'm currently working through Michael Hartl's Rails Tutorial. I'm trying to deploy my app onto Heroku, but I keep getting a 503 Error. I already called heroku run rake db:migrate as well as heroku ps:scale web=1. Neither seemed to solve my problem. Below is the return when I call heroku logs:

```
C:\Sites\rails_projects\sample_app>heroku logs
2014-09-03T01:15:48.971383+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/act
ivesupport-4.0.8/lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache.rb:83:in `call'
2014-09-03T01:15:48.971406+00:00 app[web.1]:
2014-09-03T01:15:48.971449+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rac
k-1.5.2/lib/rack/lock.rb:17:in `call'
2014-09-03T01:15:48.971459+00:00 app[web.1]:
2014-09-03T01:15:48.971363+00:00 app[web.1]: ActionController::RoutingError (No
route matches [GET] "/"):
2014-09-03T01:15:48.971370+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rai
lties-4.0.8/lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:20:in `block in call'
2014-09-03T01:15:48.971372+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/act
ivesupport-4.0.8/lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:68:in `block in tagged'
2014-09-03T01:15:48.971377+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rai
lties-4.0.8/lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:20:in `call'
2014-09-03T01:15:48.971395+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/ruby-1.9.3/lib/ruby/1.9.1/
webrick/httpserver.rb:138:in `service'
2014-09-03T01:15:48.971414+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/act
ivesupport-4.0.8/lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:68:in `block in tagged'
2014-09-03T01:15:48.971416+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/act
ivesupport-4.0.8/lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:26:in `tagged'
2014-09-03T01:15:48.971417+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/act
ivesupport-4.0.8/lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:68:in `tagged'
2014-09-03T01:15:48.971419+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rai
lties-4.0.8/lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:20:in `call'
2014-09-03T01:15:48.971420+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/act
ionpack-4.0.8/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:21:in `call'
2014-09-03T01:15:48.971398+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/ruby-1.9.3/lib/ruby/1.9.1/
webrick/server.rb:191:in `block in start_thread'
2014-09-03T01:15:48.971401+00:00 app[web.1]:
2014-09-03T01:15:48.971409+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/act
ionpack-4.0.8/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:21:in `call'
2014-09-03T01:15:48.971410+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/act
ionpack-4.0.8/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:30:in `call'
2014-09-03T01:15:48.971385+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/act
ionpack-4.0.8/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:64:in `call'
2014-09-03T01:15:48.971400+00:00 app[web.1]:
2014-09-03T01:15:48.971440+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rac
k-1.5.2/lib/rack/runtime.rb:17:in `call'
2014-09-03T01:15:48.971441+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/act
ivesupport-4.0.8/lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache.rb:83:in `call'
2014-09-03T01:15:48.971368+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rai
lties-4.0.8/lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:38:in `call_app'
2014-09-03T01:15:48.971374+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/act
ivesupport-4.0.8/lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:26:in `tagged'
2014-09-03T01:15:48.971375+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/act
ivesupport-4.0.8/lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:68:in `tagged'
2014-09-03T01:15:48.971378+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/act
ionpack-4.0.8/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:21:in `call'
2014-09-03T01:15:48.971388+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rai
lties-4.0.8/lib/rails/engine.rb:511:in `call'
2014-09-03T01:15:48.971391+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rac
k-1.5.2/lib/rack/lock.rb:17:in `call'
2014-09-03T01:15:48.971394+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rac
k-1.5.2/lib/rack/handler/webrick.rb:60:in `service'
2014-09-03T01:15:48.971444+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rac
k-1.5.2/lib/rack/sendfile.rb:112:in `call'
2014-09-03T01:15:48.971446+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rai
lties-4.0.8/lib/rails/engine.rb:511:in `call'
2014-09-03T01:15:48.971422+00:00 app[web.1]:   vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/rac
k-1.5.2/lib/rack/methodoverride.rb:21:in `call'
2014-09-03T01:16:04+00:00 heroku[slug-compiler]: Slug compilation started
2014-09-03T01:43:12+00:00 heroku[slug-compiler]: Slug compilation started
2014-09-03T01:43:34+00:00 heroku[slug-compiler]: Slug compilation failed: failed
 to compile Ruby app
2014-09-03T01:45:13+00:00 heroku[slug-compiler]: Slug compilation started
2014-09-03T01:45:37+00:00 heroku[slug-compiler]: Slug compilation failed: failed
 to compile Ruby app
2014-09-03T01:46:56+00:00 heroku[slug-compiler]: Slug compilation started
2014-09-03T01:47:19+00:00 heroku[slug-compiler]: Slug compilation failed: failed
 to compile Ruby app
2014-09-03T01:56:50+00:00 heroku[slug-compiler]: Slug compilation started
2014-09-03T01:57:13+00:00 heroku[slug-compiler]: Slug compilation failed: failed
 to compile Ruby app
2014-09-03T02:00:58.883097+00:00 heroku[api]: Starting process with command `bun
dle exec rake db:migrate` by xxxxxxxxxxx.xxx@yale.edu
2014-09-03T02:01:03.270799+00:00 heroku[run.6672]: Awaiting client
2014-09-03T02:01:03.472702+00:00 heroku[run.6672]: Starting process with command
 `bundle exec rake db:migrate`
2014-09-03T02:01:03.500688+00:00 heroku[run.6672]: State changed from starting t
o up
2014-09-03T02:01:07.922048+00:00 heroku[run.6672]: State changed from up to comp
lete
2014-09-03T02:01:07.908267+00:00 heroku[run.6672]: Process exited with status 0
2014-09-03T02:01:16+00:00 heroku[slug-compiler]: Slug compilation started
2014-09-03T02:01:43+00:00 heroku[slug-compiler]: Slug compilation failed: failed
 to compile Ruby app
2014-09-03T02:17:56+00:00 heroku[slug-compiler]: Slug compilation started
2014-09-03T02:18:33+00:00 heroku[slug-compiler]: Slug compilation failed: failed
 to compile Ruby app
2014-09-03T02:20:14.250601+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from up to down
2014-09-03T02:20:14.249756+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Idling
2014-09-03T02:20:16.243500+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Stopping all processes with SIGT
ERM
2014-09-03T02:20:16.649074+00:00 app[web.1]:    /app/vendor/ruby-1.9.3/lib/ruby/
1.9.1/webrick/server.rb:98:in `select'
2014-09-03T02:20:16.649068+00:00 app[web.1]: [2014-09-03 02:20:16] ERROR SignalE
xception: SIGTERM
2014-09-03T02:20:17+00:00 heroku[slug-compiler]: Slug compilation started
2014-09-03T02:20:27.433550+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 137
2014-09-03T02:20:26.341656+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Error R12 (Exit timeout) -> At l
east one process failed to exit within 10 seconds of SIGTERM
2014-09-03T02:20:26.341656+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Stopping remaining processes wit
h SIGKILL
2014-09-03T02:20:38+00:00 heroku[slug-compiler]: Slug compilation finished
2014-09-03T02:20:55.834230+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Unidling
2014-09-03T02:20:55.834497+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from down to start
ing
2014-09-03T02:20:58.416528+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `b
in/rails server -p 4591 -e production`
2014-09-03T02:20:59.882858+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9
.1/gems/railties-4.0.8/lib/rails/commands.rb:74:in `block in <top (required)>'
2014-09-03T02:20:59.882832+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/config/application.rb:8:in `<t
op (required)>': undefined local variable or method `config' for main:Object (Na
meError)
2014-09-03T02:20:59.882864+00:00 app[web.1]:    from bin/rails:4:in `require'
2014-09-03T02:20:59.882860+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9
.1/gems/railties-4.0.8/lib/rails/commands.rb:71:in `tap'
2014-09-03T02:20:59.882855+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9
.1/gems/railties-4.0.8/lib/rails/commands.rb:74:in `require'
2014-09-03T02:20:59.882865+00:00 app[web.1]:    from bin/rails:4:in `<main>'
2014-09-03T02:20:59.882862+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9
.1/gems/railties-4.0.8/lib/rails/commands.rb:71:in `<top (required)>'
2014-09-03T02:21:00.581910+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
2014-09-03T02:21:00.605009+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to c
rashed
2014-09-03T02:21:00.605573+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to st
arting
2014-09-03T02:21:05.096011+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `b
in/rails server -p 26610 -e production`
2014-09-03T02:21:07.464348+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9
.1/gems/railties-4.0.8/lib/rails/commands.rb:74:in `require'
2014-09-03T02:21:07.464364+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9
.1/gems/railties-4.0.8/lib/rails/commands.rb:71:in `<top (required)>'
2014-09-03T02:21:07.464366+00:00 app[web.1]:    from bin/rails:4:in `require'
2014-09-03T02:21:07.464327+00:00 app[web.1]: /app/config/application.rb:8:in `<t
op (required)>': undefined local variable or method `config' for main:Object (Na
meError)
2014-09-03T02:21:07.464351+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9
.1/gems/railties-4.0.8/lib/rails/commands.rb:74:in `block in <top (required)>'
2014-09-03T02:21:07.464352+00:00 app[web.1]:    from /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9
.1/gems/railties-4.0.8/lib/rails/commands.rb:71:in `tap'
2014-09-03T02:21:07.464367+00:00 app[web.1]:    from bin/rails:4:in `<main>'
2014-09-03T02:21:08.367706+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
2014-09-03T02:21:08.385828+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to c
rashed
2014-09-03T02:21:09.878185+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App cra
shed" method=GET path="/" host=stark-wildwood-4373.herokuapp.com request_id=9609
1c6b-8b29-46c7-9346-7958d56ca8b6 fwd="54.81.14.127" dyno= connect= service= stat
us=503 bytes=
2014-09-03T02:21:24.250818+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App cra
shed" method=GET path="/" host=stark-wildwood-4373.herokuapp.com request_id=bf7f
ebce-27ea-4f27-a7ec-e10847f981b9 fwd="130.132.173.192" dyno= connect= service= s
tatus=503 bytes=
2014-09-03T02:21:45.319045+00:00 heroku[api]: Starting process with command `bun
dle exec rake db:migrate` by xxxxxxxxxxx.xxx@yale.edu
2014-09-03T02:21:48.040435+00:00 heroku[run.5773]: Awaiting client
2014-09-03T02:21:48.076415+00:00 heroku[run.5773]: Starting process with command
 `bundle exec rake db:migrate`
2014-09-03T02:21:48.398535+00:00 heroku[run.5773]: State changed from starting t
o up
2014-09-03T02:21:50.510559+00:00 heroku[run.5773]: Process exited with status 1
2014-09-03T02:21:59.387968+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App cra
shed" method=GET path="/" host=stark-wildwood-4373.herokuapp.com request_id=0ab1
0c21-51b8-4b88-b820-6814a2c31703 fwd="130.132.173.192" dyno= connect= service= s
tatus=503 bytes=
2014-09-03T02:22:22.149895+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App cra
shed" method=GET path="/" host=stark-wildwood-4373.herokuapp.com request_id=adcb
f705-d59b-4267-96ed-6beccafbb804 fwd="130.132.173.192" dyno= connect= service= s
tatus=503 bytes=
2014-09-03T02:27:41.888659+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App cra
shed" method=GET path="/" host=stark-wildwood-4373.herokuapp.com request_id=f0ca
3a90-2fa4-4caa-a8d4-6117a5d2a1d4 fwd="130.132.173.192" dyno= connect= service= s
tatus=503 bytes=
2014-09-03T02:35:36.956599+00:00 heroku[api]: Scale to web=1 by xxxxxxxxxxx.xxx@
yale.edu
2014-09-03T02:35:43.542084+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App cra
shed" method=GET path="/" host=stark-wildwood-4373.herokuapp.com request_id=3e14
7f38-6946-49bd-a616-5d4476cfb125 fwd="130.132.173.192" dyno= connect= service= s
tatus=503 bytes=
2014-09-03T03:11:23.633738+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App cra
shed" method=GET path="/" host=stark-wildwood-4373.herokuapp.com request_id=73fd
0f48-3813-4cdf-883c-89c2c07d891a fwd="130.132.173.192" dyno= connect= service= s
tatus=503 bytes=
2014-09-03T03:18:30.294561+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App cra
shed" method=HEAD path="/" host=stark-wildwood-4373.herokuapp.com request_id=a12
3c40c-94c2-460b-906d-8a2cc5af1af5 fwd="216.46.190.189, 10.160.107.8,50.18.102.13
2" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
2014-09-03T03:18:30.226691+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App cra
shed" method=HEAD path="/" host=stark-wildwood-4373.herokuapp.com request_id=8f5
1f503-d0ef-476a-ae29-c5aa6c4696bd fwd="216.46.175.33, 10.166.163.136,50.18.102.1
32" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes=
2014-09-03T03:21:35+00:00 heroku[slug-compiler]: Slug compilation started
2014-09-03T03:21:58+00:00 heroku[slug-compiler]: Slug compilation failed: failed
 to compile Ruby app
```

The /config/application.rb file is given as follows:

```
require File.expand_path('../boot', __FILE__)

# Pick the frameworks you want:
require "active_record/railtie"
require "action_controller/railtie"
require "action_mailer/railtie"
require "sprockets/railtie"
# require "rails/test_unit/railtie"

# Require the gems listed in Gemfile, including any gems
# you've limited to :test, :development, or :production.
Bundler.require(*Rails.groups)

module SampleApp
  class Application < Rails::Application
    # Settings in config/environments/* take precedence over those specified here.
    # Application configuration should go into files in config/initializers
    # -- all .rb files in that directory are automatically loaded.

    # Set Time.zone default to the specified zone and make Active Record auto-convert     to this zone.
    # Run "rake -D time" for a list of tasks for finding time zone names. Default is     UTC.
    # config.time_zone = 'Central Time (US & Canada)'

    # The default locale is :en and all translations from config/locales/*.rb,yml are     auto loaded.
    # config.i18n.load_path += Dir[Rails.root.join('my', 'locales', '*.{rb,yml}').to_s]
    # config.i18n.default_locale = :de
    config.assets.initialize_on_precompile = false
    config.assets.precompile += %w(*.png *.jpg *.jpeg *.gif)
  end
end
```

I apologize for this monstrous block of errors, but I'm really stuck here. If any more information is needed, I will be more than happy to provide. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Can you post more of the error? You can do something such as `heroku logs -n 300` and/or `heroku logs -t` (the latter will scroll as new messages are added to the log aka "tailing")

Comment: The issue is around line 8 of `/app/config/application.rb` (`undefined local variable or method `config' for main:Object`)

Comment: Is your code in a github repo or is the tutorial you are following open source? (link?)

Comment: The code is in a github repository. I just ran heroku logs -t, and the output is super long. I will post more of the error once I format it correctly.

Comment: No need to do anything other than post the code. The issue has to do with the `config` variable not being defined. You're probably trying to load a file that wasn't committed or deployed to the Heroku repo.

Comment: Right. I don't even have the app/config directory, so I'm not sure why the log is asking for /app/config/application.rb.

Comment: Maybe you should? Can you post application.rb or at least the first few lines?

Comment: Err, I mean the app/config directory has not been made, so the /app/config/application.rb doesn't exist. I do, however, have the /config/application.rb file, which I will edit right now into the post.

Comment: `config.assets.initialize_on_precompile = false` should probably be *inside* class Application

Comment: I put that line into the class Application, but when I run 'git push heroku', I get the error:

Precompiling assets failed.

Push rejected, failed to compile Ruby app.

Comment: I just updated the heroku logs after getting the precompiling assets failure. I also updated the /config/application.rb file

Comment: Are you sure you have placed all the right files under /stylesheets and /javascripts ?

Comment: Heroku actually puts your application in another `app/` folder, so your `config/application.rb` becomes `app/config/application.rb` on Heroku. No need to worry about that though. Try pushing your application again, and keep an eye on the logs to see what error it gives when precompiling assets.

Comment: Is your website working in local ? Be sure that it is before deploying to heroku.

What I notice is this line.

ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/"):
I think a first step would be to add to config/routes.rb

match '/', :to => 'pages#home'
Replacing pages#home by your_controller#your_home_method

Comment: @Mariekou The website is working in local - in my app/config/environments.rb, I have the line config.consider_all_requests_local       = true. I took a look at my config/routes.rb and I noticed a missing '/' However, even when I added it in, I still get the error when precompiling assets. Also, I already put root 'static_pages#home'. They are the same thing, right?

Comment: Yes this is correct. Have you checked your production.rb file ? Maybe you have an extra 'end' or something